# Golfing rotations

Tags: combinations

Let's say there are 10 golfers playing a mini 3 round tournament, 1 round on each of 3 consecutive days.  Each day they are split in to 2 groups of 5 golfers.  Is it possible that, by the time the tournament is over, each golfer has played with each other golfer at least once?

Follow up question:  If it is not possible, what is the largest grouping size for which it is possible?

Edit:
By "largest grouping size" I mean, what is the largest N such that N golfers can be split in to 2 groups of N/2 each day and by the end each of the N golfers will have played with each other golfer.

Comment: With 8 golfers, they can first split into four pairs, with tournament {AB, CD}, {AC, BD}, {AD, BC}.

Comment: With 9 golfers, this is impossible, as 9 is odd.  Hence it only remains to prove that it's not possible with 10 golfers.

Comment: Simulations give N=4. Even for 6 golfers there are at least two pairs that wouldn't play in 3 days.

Comment: @vadim123 Your example seems to me to be for N=4 not N=8.  Am I missing something?

Comment: The golfers split into 4 pairs: A, B, C, D.  A=1+2, B=3+4, C=5+6, D=7+8.

Comment: Gotcha. Sorry, I thought when you said pairs that `AB` was the pair not that each of A and B represents a pair.  Interestingly though, does this not prove that it is always possible for any N divisible by 4?